# JPQL query that joins two tables and get results in a single ArrayList

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

One to Many relationships

JPQL query that joins across two table

```
select a.owner, b.member 
from EntityA a JOIN a.entityB b 
where a.id=b.group.id
```

and the result will be a `List<Object[2]>`

Is it possible to make it a List of String as the `a.owner` and `b.member` are Strings, joining these two objects to a single List of String?

Answer (score 0):

SQL supports UNION, but JPQL does not. You could merge the both list using Java after getting the result set.

Native Query may be an option. Emulate UNION statement with subqueries can be another option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) for this which works on top of JPA and provides support for set operations. A query could look like the following

```
List<String> list = criteriaBuilderFactory.create(entityManager, String.class)
    .from(EntityA.class, "a")
    .select("a.owner")
  .unionAll()
    .from(EntityB.class, "b")
    .select("b.member")
  .end()
  .getResultList();
```

After setting Blaze-Persistence up like described in the [documentation](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#environments-spring) you can create a repository like this:

```
@Component
class MyRepository {
  @Autowired CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf;
  @Autowired EntityManager em;

  public List<String> getList() {
    return cbf.create(em, String.class)
        .from(EntityA.class, "a")
        .select("a.owner")
      .unionAll()
        .from(EntityB.class, "b")
        .select("b.member")
      .end()
      .getResultList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a constructor in the `SELECT`. The specified class is not required to be an entity or to be mapped to the database. The constructor name must be fully qualified.

```
// let's say you have a class to keep your 2 Strings

package a.b.c;

public class MyResult {
    private String aOwner;
    private String bMember;

    // you need this constructor
    public MyResult(String a, String b) {
        aOwner = a;
        bMember = b;
    }

    // getters
}
```

And then you can use your class directly to get `List<MyResult>` instead of List of arrays or something:

```
SELECT NEW a.b.c.MyResult(a.owner, b.member)
FROM ......
```

Usually, it is a good idea to use the SELECT NEW when you don't want to retrieve a full entity or a full graph of objects in a type-safe way (as opposed to an Object[]).